# How can i write this function using SAL annotations for C in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, annotations, sal

How can i write this function using SAL annotations for C? I need to implement some functions and i dont know how to declare them. I just need 1 function as a model, so i can implement the rest.

Down here is my main C file with take all the hanldes i have implemented, i dont need to modifiy this.

```
static void
PrintHelp()
{
    printf("Available commands:\n");
    printf("\t> register <username> <password>\n");
    printf("\t> login <username> <password>\n");
    printf("\t> logout\n");
    printf("\t> store <source file path> <submission name>\n");
    printf("\t> retrieve <submission name> <destination file path>\n");
    printf("\t> exit\n");
}

int main()
{
    char command[10];
    char arg1[50];
    char arg2[50];

    NTSTATUS status = GlobalDataInitialize();
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        printf("GlobalDataInitialize failed with NTSTATUS = 0x%X\n", status);
        assert(FALSE);
        return -1;
    }

    PrintHelp();
    do
    {
        printf("Enter your command:\n");
        scanf("%s", command);

        if (memcmp(command, "register", sizeof("register")) == 0)
        {
            scanf("%s", arg1);    // username
            scanf("%s", arg2);    // password

            printf("register with username [%s] password [%s]\n", arg1, arg2);
            SafeStorageHandleRegister(arg1, (USHORT)strlen(arg1), arg2, (USHORT)strlen(arg2));
        }
        else if (memcmp(command, "login", sizeof("login")) == 0)
        {
            scanf("%s", arg1);    // username
            scanf("%s", arg2);    // password

            printf("login with username [%s] password [%s]\n", arg1, arg2);
            SafeStorageHandleLogin(arg1, (USHORT)strlen(arg1), arg2, (USHORT)strlen(arg2));
        }
        else if (memcmp(command, "logout", sizeof("logout")) == 0)
        {
            printf("logout\n");
            SafeStorageHandleLogout();
        }
        else if (memcmp(command, "store", sizeof("store")) == 0)
        {
            scanf("%s", arg1);    // source file path
            scanf("%s", arg2);    // submission name

            printf("store with source file path [%s] submission name [%s]\n", arg1, arg2);
            SafeStorageHandleStore(arg2, (USHORT)strlen(arg2), arg1, (USHORT)strlen(arg1));
        }
        else if (memcmp(command, "retrieve", sizeof("retrieve")) == 0)
        {
            scanf("%s", arg1);    // submission name 
            scanf("%s", arg2);    // destination file path

            printf("retrieve with submission name [%s] destination file path [%s]\n", arg1, arg2);
            SafeStorageHandleRetrieve(arg1, (USHORT)strlen(arg1), arg2, (USHORT)strlen(arg2));
        }
        else if (memcmp(command, "exit", sizeof("exit")) == 0)
        {
            printf("Bye Bye!\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Unknown command. Try again!\n");
        }
    } while (TRUE);

    return 0;
```

I need help implementing this registration handle function. I can see that this registration functions has these 2 parameters *Username**Password* and also define the type of data. I dont know how to write proper C declarations using SAL annotations to make this work.

```
// Handles the "register" command
// Creates the user with Username and Password specified
//      * Creates the user's subdirectory in the %APPDIR%\users directory
// Fails if the user is already registered
// This command is available only if no user is currently logged in (it must fail otherwise)
// It returns STATUS_SUCCESS if everything succeeded or a proper error status otherwise.

_Must_inspect_result_
NTSTATUS
SafeStorageHandleRegister(
    _In_reads_bytes_opt_(UsernameLength) PCHAR Username,
    _In_ USHORT UsernameLength,
    _In_reads_bytes_opt_(PasswordLength) PCHAR Password, 
    _In_ USHORT PasswordLength);
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what the errors you are seeing are?   I think I see some issues with the way the function is being called.

Answer (score 1):

*Addressing the call to `SafeStorageHandleRegister()`:*

Given your original prototype:

```
SafeStorageHandleRegister(
_In_reads_bytes_opt_(UsernameLength) PCHAR Username,
_In_ USHORT UsernameLength,
_In_reads_bytes_opt_(PasswordLength) PCHAR Password, 
_In_ USHORT PasswordLength);
```

One issue is that in your call:

```
SafeStorageHandleRegister(arg1, (USHORT)strlen(arg1), arg2, (USHORT)strlen(arg2));
```

...the number of bytes specified in arguments 3 & 4 does not include room for the null byte, resulting in an incorrect *number of bytes* value.
`strlen()` does not include `\0` in its calculation, but `\0` *is* at the end of all C strings (which are being used here.) Use `sizeof(arg1)` and `sizeof(arg2)` instead.  eg:

```
SafeStorageHandleRegister(arg1, (USHORT)sizeof(arg1), arg2, (USHORT)sizeof(arg2));
```

And, because the `sizeof` macro returns `size_t` if this is your function prototype, (i.e. one that you can modify.) I suggest changing it from using `USHORT` to `size_t` for the 2nd and 4th arguments:

```
SafeStorageHandleRegister(
_In_reads_bytes_opt_(UsernameLength) PCHAR Username,
_In_ size_t UsernameLength,
_In_reads_bytes_opt_(PasswordLength) PCHAR Password, 
_In_ size_t PasswordLength);
```

...making it more readable because there will be no casts:

```
SafeStorageHandleRegister(arg1, sizeof(arg1), arg2, sizeof(arg2));
```

_Addressing potential issues for SAL notations:

This may or may not be causing your failure, but important to note anyway...

> *"If the caller is not allowed to pass in a null pointer, use `_In_` or `_Out_` instead of `_In_opt_` or `_Out_opt_`. This applies even to a function that checks its parameters and returns an error if it is NULL
> when it should not be."*...

So, for example:

```
// Incorrect
void Func1(_Out_opt_ int *p1)
{
    *p = 1;
}

// Correct
void Func2(_Out_ int *p1)
{
    *p = 1;
}
```

Since you do not want your functions to have the *option* to pass `NULL` pointers it would be good to consider modifying the SAL notation from `_In_reads_bytes_opt_` to `_In_reads_bytes_` (removing the option)

```
 SafeStorageHandleRegister(
_In_reads_bytes(UsernameLength) PCHAR Username,
_In_ size_t UsernameLength,
_In_reads_bytes(PasswordLength) PCHAR Password, 
_In_ size_t PasswordLength);
```

Much more on [SAL notations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/best-practices-and-examples-sal?view=msvc-160).